# Setting Application User Model ID of other process

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a launcher app that starts another app. For the other App to play nicely with Windows 7's taskbars, I have to set the [Application User Model ID](http://windowsteamblog.com/windows/b/developers/archive/2009/06/18/developing-for-the-windows-7-taskbar-application-id.aspx).

Usually a process has to set this id for itself, by calling SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID(), but in this specific case I do not have control about the other apps startup code, so I have to set this externally, at best by using some kind of ShellExecute which passes the ID to the app.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why does this other application need a explicit id?

Answer (score 3):

Windows will auto generate a id for the process if it does not call SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID, this should be enough for the recent files jumplist section.

If you for whatever reason really want to set a specific id for a 3rd party app, I would try one of these (I have not tried any of these suggestions)

- use SHGetPropertyStoreForWindow on the apps window (I have never tried to set the id like this, but I know you can read the id of another process this way)
- Create a temporary shortcut that launches the app with a specific id
- Inject into the process and call SetCurrentProcessExplicitAppUserModelID

Comment: Okey, just tried, and the second option has its drawback, also. Problem is: I have a Java app that is started from a launcher, which checks for updates. The Java App is compiled with Exe4J, which itself shows a splashscreen, which results in an icon in the taskbar. For the time of the splash screen shown I have two icons in the taskbar, because the Java app does not inherit the app id from the parent process, and it is too late the app id from the java app itself, because the splash screen shows intentionally before the jvm is loaded.

Comment: @Daniel: Well, maybe you could ask the Exe4J people to add app model id support, or write your own launcher

Comment: I already did ask them, but I still don't know, when they will implement my requirements. Maybe I should buy a support package, but I don't want this for now... not if I can still achive this differently :).